# jQuery animated circular progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a jQuery script for an animated circular progress bar. Right now the progress bar works when the start button is clicked. I want this progress bar to start when the user scrolls to the div id "stats" automatically. How can this be done?

I have made a fiddle to show what I have so far: 
https://jsfiddle.net/rpkcw236/9/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.pie_progress').asPieProgress({
    namespace: 'pie_progress',
    barsize: '2',
    trackcolor: '#ececea',
    barcolor: '#e6675f'
});
$('#button_start').on('click', function(){
    $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress('start');
});
$('#button_finish').on('click', function(){
     $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress('finish');
});
$('#button_go').on('click', function(){
     $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress('go',50);
});
$('#button_go_percentage').on('click', function(){
    $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress('go','50%');
});
$('#button_stop').on('click', function(){
    $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress('stop');
});
$('#button_reset').on('click', function(){
    $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress('reset');
});
});
```

Here is the link to the script I am using: 
http://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Animated-Circle-Progress-Bar-with-jQuery-SVG-asPieProgress.html

Comment: _"I want this progress bar to start when the user scrolls to the div id "stats" automatically"_ No scrollable content appears at https://jsfiddle.net/rpkcw236/7/ ?

Comment: added placeholder content so that the page is scrollable now.

https://jsfiddle.net/rpkcw236/8/

Comment: `.asPieProgress` is not defined at https://jsfiddle.net/rpkcw236/8/

Comment: i had loaded the script from a GitHub link, i guess because of that it was not working. Updated it and now the script is inside JSFIDDLE Javascript section:

https://jsfiddle.net/rpkcw236/9/

Comment: Please check the updated code, I've tested on your fiddle & works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to break it up into 2 steps: 
1) get the distance of the dynamic div from the top. 
2) Once you get the top value pass this top value to the code in step2.

**Step1:** Get the dynamic div position from the top (e.g. #my-dynamic-div)

```
    var $output = $('#output');
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop(),
    elementOffset = $('#my-dynamic-div').offset().top,
    distance      = (elementOffset - scrollTop);
    $output.prepend('<p>' + distance + '</p>');
    });

    OR

    E.G: var distance = $("#MyDiv").offset().top
```

ref: http://jsfiddle.net/Rxs2m/

**Step2:** Pass the distance value here instead of the hard coded value 350.

```
flag=true;

$(window).scroll(function() {
st=$(window).scrollTop();
$('#topscroll').html(st)


if(st>350){
    if(flag)
     $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress('start');
    flag=false;
}
});
```

Good luck & hope this helps.

Comment: "if (st>350)". The content  is going to be dynamic so we cannot set a fixed height. This needs to be calculated automatically for dynamic content.

Comment: You need to break it up into 2 steps, 1) get the distance of the dynamic div from the top. 2) Once you get the top value pass this top value to the above code. That's all.

Answer (score 2):

Try using <strike>`.scrollTop()` , `.offset().top`</strike> `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` of `#progress` element, `.off()`

```
  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if ($("#progress")[0].getBoundingClientRect().top < 150) {
      $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress('start')
      $(this).off("scroll")
    }
  })
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rpkcw236/29/

Comment: i want to omit clicking on #button_start. I want it to start automatically when window is scrolled to #progress.

Comment: _"i want to omit clicking on #button_start. I want it to start automatically when window is scrolled to #progress."_ ? Have you tried jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rpkcw236/10/ ? The animation does start when scroll to `#progress` by using existing `click` handler. You could alternatively use `if ($(this).scrollTop() + 20 >= $("#progress").offset().top) { $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress('start');}`

Comment: my requirement is that the click handler should not be needed for the animation to start and it should start when window is scrolled to progress. Can you please update your new code to the JSFIDDLE _"if ($(this).scrollTop() + 20 >= $("#progress").offset().top) { $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress('start');} "_

Comment: this gives me an error "TypeError Offset is undefined" and the JSFIDDLE does not work either. Maybe I havent been very clear with the requirements. I have just removed the Start button from the JSFIDDLE since the functionality that I am looking for does not require clicking the start button. Check this fiddle: 

https://jsfiddle.net/rpkcw236/18/

Comment: @AlexZahir See updated post; substituted `getBoundingClientRect()` for `.offset().top` , `.scrollTop()`

Comment: I get a TypeError [0] is undefined. Maybe you should check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36090630/jquery-scripts-overlapping-each-others-functionality/36091075#36091075

Comment: no but when i use your code locally i get TypeError.

Comment: _"no but when i use your code locally i get TypeError."_ Is the same `html`, `js` used locally and jsfiddle ?

Comment: Then there should not be an error. Can you reproduce error at plnkr http://plnkr.co or jsfiddle ?